# how can i modify the RWX attribute of function in LLVM IR?

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

Due to project requirements, i need to modify the RXW attribute of some functions. Such as modify a function attribute to WX. I tried to separate the functions in different sections, but what problem is that i don't know how to modify those attribute in LLVM IR. Is there any good way?

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding here. You don't modify a function as RWX, you mark the memory page containing that function to be RWX.

You choices would be:
- Post process after the file has been linked
- Use LLVM IR to add external function calls to system API which will mark the memory page as RWX